# Rosetta Stone puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

The answer to this puzzle is one word.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line shows

> lots of threes.

The second says

> $\left(\frac{2838}{43\cdot\sqrt{36}}\right)^3-\frac{23}{360}\cdot\left(\frac{238}{34}\right)!$

in

> $\left(\frac{\textrm{Greek}}{\textrm{Khmer}\cdot\sqrt{\textrm{Armenian}}}\right)^?-\frac{\textrm{modern Western}}{\textrm{Chinese}}\cdot\left(\frac{\textrm{Hebrew}}{\textrm{Indian}}\right)!$ numerals

yielding

> 1009

which

> in Roman numerals, which we haven't used yet, gives **MIX**.

Confessions:

> I don't know what the ? is, but it's clearly 3 (1) just from looking at it and (2) because it appears on the first line, which is all threes. I'm not sure whether "Armenian" is right. The thing I've labelled as Khmer seems like the first figure is Khmer and the second is Thai. I am not an expert on any of this stuff.

Comment: Well $\beta$, $\omega$, $\lambda$ and $\eta$ are not greek *numerals*, but I understand the correspondence you have used :P

Comment: See the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_numerals).

Comment: I stand corrected. $(+1)$